# Count data for 15 minute intervals that are grouped by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL table:

```
+---------------------+-----------+
|      timestamp      | sensor_id |
+---------------------+-----------+
| 2010-04-09 01:42:31 |    M049   |
| 2010-04-09 01:43:31 |    M049   |
| 2010-04-09 01:44:31 |    M049   |
| 2010-04-09 01:59:31 |    M049   |
| 2010-04-10 01:10:31 |    M049   |
| 2010-04-10 01:40:31 |    M049   |
| 2010-04-10 01:42:31 |    M049   |
| 2010-04-11 16:43:31 |    M049   |
+---------------------+-----------+
```

I know how to query the db to get a count of the entries for a specific daytime intervall and group the result by date.

An example to query the event count between 1 am and 2 pm would look like this:

```
SELECT
    date(timestamp) as date,
    count(timestamp) as count
FROM 
    event_data
WHERE 
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIME(timestamp)) BETWEEN 1 AND 14
GROUP BY 
    date
```

The query returns the following table:

```
+------------+-------+
|    date    | count |
+------------+-------+
| 2010-04-09 |   4   |
| 2010-04-10 |   3   |
+------------+-------+
```

Now I only want to count an event every 15 minutes.
The desired result would be:

```
+------------+-------+
|    date    | count |
+------------+-------+
| 2010-04-09 |   2   |
| 2010-04-10 |   2   |
+------------+-------+
```

How do I alter my query to get these results?

Comment: Just for clarification, you only want the number of times *any* event occurred in fifteen minutes? So, you can have a max of 4 events per hour?

Comment: That is exactly what i want.

Comment: Another clarification needed, do you want to create the time buckets per 15 minutes (eg: 2010-04-09 13:00, 2010-04-09 13:15 ...), or refered by time from a row (eg: 2010-04-10 01:40,2010-04-10 01:55 ...)?

Comment: Either one would solve my problem.

Comment: Buff, that makes complex answer. If you make buckets, you just need to create a dimension table containing dates with 15 min of difference between them, then join with your main table and get a count. If you go for my second part of the question, then you just need to make a windowing query. Either way complex

Comment: I think, you just need to create the buckets, if I undertood the question you mention grouped by date.

Comment: I agree with @husker. If you meant to look 15 minute intervals based on the timestamps you have, it could get really complicated. If you just want the four 15 minute intervals in an hour, it's not that bad. I would recommend clarifying what you really need here, because the two may not give the same answer.

Comment: Just one thing, in your desired output I can't see that is correct, you have 3 hits in 15 min on the 2010-04-09 not 2. The next day is correct, based on bucket approach

Comment: @husker see my first comment on the post. They're not counting the number of hits in a 15 minute interval, they're counting the number of 15 minute intervals that have at least one record.

Comment: @McAdam331 thanks, that's why I posted my doubts

Comment: @husker I thought the same thing as you when I read it the first time. That's what I tried to clarify.

Comment: Thanks guys, i really appreciate your help. McAdam331 is right. I want to count 15 minute intervals that have at least one record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a good start to group by date and query for the hours you want. Similarly, you can write a query that gets the intervals. I would start by writing a case statement that reads each row you want, and adds a column specifying which interval of the hour it is. (0:14 - 1, 15:29 - 2...) like this:

```
SELECT timeCol, 
  HOUR(timeCol) AS hour,
  CASE WHEN MINUTE(timeCol) BETWEEN 0 AND 14 THEN 1
  WHEN MINUTE(timeCol) BETWEEN 15 AND 29 THEN 2
  WHEN MINUTE(timeCol) BETWEEN 30 AND 44 THEN 3
  ELSE 4 END AS minute
FROM myTable;
```

This gives you something like this:

```
|      timeCol        | hour | minute |
+---------------------+------+--------+
| 2010-04-09 01:42:31 |  1   |   3    |
| 2010-04-09 01:43:31 |  1   |   3    |
| 2010-04-09 01:44:31 |  1   |   3    |
```

Once you have that, you can select the distinct hour/minute pairs in each day, and that will give you what you want, as long as you use your WHERE clause accordingly:

```
SELECT DATE(timeCol) AS dateCol, COUNT(DISTINCT hour, minute) AS numEvents
FROM(
  SELECT timeCol, 
    HOUR(timeCol) AS hour,
    CASE WHEN MINUTE(timeCol) BETWEEN 0 AND 14 THEN 1
    WHEN MINUTE(timeCol) BETWEEN 15 AND 29 THEN 2
    WHEN MINUTE(timeCol) BETWEEN 30 AND 44 THEN 3
    ELSE 4 END AS minute
  FROM myTable) tmp
WHERE HOUR(timecol) BETWEEN 1 AND 14
GROUP BY dateCol;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaf1b/5) example.

I would just like to add that you don't have to record the intervals as 1, 2, 3, 4. Make sure you use something readable, that will make sense to you again in the future. For example, maybe something like this would be better:

```
WHEN MINUTE(timeCol) BETWEEN 0 and 14 THEN 'firstInterval'...
```

Comment: I think this solves my problem. After I have implemented everything and it works as expected I will accept your answer. Thank you very much!